# Sass gem conflicting with framework installations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, zurb-foundation, neat, zurb-foundation-5

I was trying to set up Foundation 5 and now have switched to Neat because of several issues preventing it from installing properly. One of the blogs I troubleshooted with had me remove the sass gem and install it again. I broke something a long the way because now I can't even set up Neat.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sass":
  In Gemfile:
    sass-rails (~> 4.0.3) ruby depends on
      sass (~> 3.2.2) ruby

    sass (3.4.11)
```

This is after running bundle update sass. I'm just trying to get a clean environment again so I set up the Neat framework.

Here is the last troubleshooting attempt I made before scrapping Foundation: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/pull/5651

Answer (score 1):

If you are using RVM (if you're not, I recommend you do!), you could try setting up your project using a new gemset.

This is basically a seperate environment for you to install your gems.

[RVM Documentation](https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics)